# Can we add a 'split answer' feature?

Tags: feature-request, answers

It's really annoying when someone answers a question like 'what is your fave tool?' and they write 4 in a bulleted list. This makes it hard to comment on the individual bits. It would be cool if you could drag over one of the answers, hit the 'split to new answer' button and have it become its own item.

Comment: Why? If another answer is also valid, it will get plenty of upvotes. Accepting one as answer is basically just another upvote with a slightly bigger value.

Comment: You should add a comment to the poster to indicate which part you disagree with, and they might change that part if they agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

Since this kind of question is tolerated at max, but definitely not encouraged, I don't think there's much to be done.

Also, this sounds close-to-impossible to reasonably implement UI-wise. If you have strong feelings about a particular case, you can post a new answer with one part of the source answer, and edit the source answer to remove the migrated part.

Comment: In that case you would get the reputation for the new question and not the original answerer.

Comment: @Eric: Questions like this should be wiki basically *by definition*. There's no rep involved.

Comment: @balpha: Good point, but it's still questionable.  Badges can be awarded for wiki questions, and people are generally against answer 'stealing' and this could be viewed as such even if the intentions were honest.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @balpha: Editing someone's answer to improve it and editing someone's answer to remove content which you have posted, after the fact, as a different answer are separate things. The former is encouraged. The latter is, in my opinion, even worse than just copying and pasting someone's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Trilogy strongly discourages discussion type or list type questions, although to some degree some exists, this is really not a needed feature. Comment to the OP and ask them to break up the answer, and since these questions are meant to be CW, they won't have any rep gain either way.

I don't see a need for this. Anything to discourage users to post discussion or open ended questions I would welcome with open arms.

As [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/can-we-add-a-split-answer-feature/22533#22533) pointed out it will also be a pain to implement. What logic do you use? Split by line? Split by word?